# Pass one object value to another object

Tags: c#, object

How do I pass one object value to another object that needs the same value
For example: 
If I have

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
```

Call a method to get all of the contact information and now I have contact.id available

The scheduler method which is expecting a personId which is the contact.id
Without doing `scheduler.personId = contact.id` and passing the value to LoadScheduler what is the proper way? thx

```
private void LoadSchedule(Scheduler scheduler)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Cant understand what you are asking.

Comment: kinda lost on what you ask for. what does the design looks like? how does the scheduler relates to the contacts? But in any way, why would you link things via ids? if the scheduler has business with contacts, pas the instance of the contact to the scheduler and let the scheduler do whatever it needs to do with the provided information. if you are trying to hide functionality put it behind an interface. but most important: what is the design issue?

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to ask>> pass the instance of the contact to the scheduler and let the scheduler do whatever it needs to do with the provided information, so I pass LoadSchedule(Scheduler, contact)??

Comment: To help better, tell us why do you think your approach is wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing isn't wrong.

```
scheduler.personId = contact.id
LoadSchedule(scheduler);
```

Or otherwise you would need better argument for your method..

```
LoadSchedule(contact.id);
...
private void LoadSchedule(int contactId)
{

}
```

But then you wouldn't have all the fields of `Scheduler` object to access. But if that matters..

Or even:

```
LoadSchedule(contact);
...
private Scheduler LoadSchedule(Contact contact)
{
     Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler { personId = contact.id };
     //load...
     return scheduler;
}
```

Or you can have a proper instance method (or extension method) to load schedule from the scheduler object.

```
class Scheduler
{
    public void Load()
    {

    }
}
```

So now you can call just `scheduler.Load()` once you have the right instance.. All these aren't wrong, but depends on which class/layer you need the logics to be in. Without knowing the domain, its hard to say which is the best. *Give the job to the right class*. To help better, tell us why do you think your approach is wrong in the first place?